# Getting Molecular Orbital contributions to the ESP fitted charges

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

For a single determinant wavefunction, the electron density is the sum of the densities arising from each molecular orbital. The molecular Electrostatic potential $\phi_{mol}$ is calculated from the total density and therefore, at a given point $\vec{R}$, its value is given by the sum of all the contributions arising from each MO.
\begin{equation}
\phi_{mol}(\vec{R})=\sum_{i=1}^{N_{MO}} \phi_{i}(\vec{R})
\end{equation}
Atomic partial charges can be obtained by fitting the total molecular ESP in different flavors and with different constraints, however I am interested in knowing for a given atom $I$, the charge contribution of each molecular orbital to the total ESP-fitted charge, namely the elements in the summation below
\begin{equation}
q^{_I}=\sum_{i=1}^{N_{MO}} q_{i}^{_I}
\end{equation}
Is there anyone knowing a software for wavefunction-analysis that can do this from a wfn file or a way of getting the solution without writing a piece of code from sctratch?